# node js module.exports of a module argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new in *Node.js*, and I've created a module based on mongoose but i have a problem with the configuration function.

Actually my module uses the **mongoose.connect** connection, but i want to change it in order to use **mongoose.createConnection**. To do this I've created an **init** function that accept the connection string as an argument.

My problem is "How can I **module.exports** the connection into my module?"

For example:

```
// server.js
var mymodule = require('mymodule');
mymodule.init('http://localhost:27017/test');

// mymodule/index.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = {
  init: function(connString){
    module.exports = connection = mongoose.createConnection(connString); // this is wrong
  }
}

// mymodule/user.js
// I want to use the connection to create the mongoose 'User' model
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
var connection = require // I don't know
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

module.exports = connection.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If it's synchronous, just return it?

Comment: Thx for the reply, if i understand what you mean in this case i would have something like this in the server.js:
var connection = mymodule.init('http://...');
But this is not good for me i wanna use the connection to configure the module.
I hope that i understand your advice.
I tried also to inject the connection into the User model
something like require('./mymodule/model/user')(connection) but i have the same problem in the model.

Answer (score 1):

`mongoose.createConnection()` is synchronous, so you should be able to just return the connection from your method.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = {
  init: function(connString){
    return mongoose.createConnection(connString);
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var module = require('myModule');
var db = module.init('mongodb://etc/db');
```

Comment: Thx for your reply.

This solution doesn't fits for me, because i wanna use the connection internally to my module, I would create the connection in the init method and share it into the mymodule/models/ files. I need something to inject my connection into my models.